# How to convert interval to number of seconds in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert this field to the number of seconds?

```
({{%event}}.created_at - (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL \'3600 SECOND\') as time_left'
```

Comment: Assuming you mean `epoch`: `select extract(epoch from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3600 SECOND'); 1678201734.244580`.